# Calling a function from a funtion pointer in a map C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dictionary

So I am unsure why this wont work, ive tried some googling, i just cant find out what the problem is

```
void Player::Cmd(std::vector<std::string> &tokens)
{
std::string str = tokens[0];
std::map<std::string, void (Player::*)()>::iterator it = playerCommands.find(str);

Func fun;
if (it != playerCommands.end())
{

    fun = it->second; //i tried it->second(); same issue
    fun();  //error C2064: term does not evaluate to a 
            //function taking 0 arguments

}
else
{
    std::cout << "What? \n";
}
}
```

git hub for the project 
https://github.com/lordkuragari/TextRPG

Comment: What happens if tokens is empty?

Comment: Your value in the map are pointers to member functions, you need an actual instance to be able to "call" the function.

Comment: @NeilKirk indeed this isnt bug proof, i just got stuck on this an could get past it, i desided to check for an empty string before calling this fuction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to your belief, your map doesn't hold function pointers. So you cannot *call* the elements in the map.

Rather, your map contains *pointers to member functions*. Non-static member functions aren't functions and cannot be called; rather, they have to be invoked on an *object*. You can invoke a member function on an object given by a pointer `p` via a function pointer `ptfm` like this:

```
(p->*ptmf)();
```

In your case, presumably you want to use `p = this` and `ptfm = fun`, so it'd be:

```
(this->*fun)();
```

Or, without the local variable:

```
(this->*it->second)();
```

In C++17 you can also [use](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/537ddf8469de7ebe274c243be713482031623a34) `std::invoke(it->second, this)`.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Get with the times, grandpa :-)

Comment: How can there be 17 when it's still 2014, why 17 and not 18?

Comment: @NeilKirk: The targeted release cycle is every three years. C++14 is done and out of the door and should be available in print soon.

Comment: thank you, works. i just thought that because i was in the class I didnt need to make a reference to this. TIL

Comment: @LordKuragari: hm, I think you're confusing *names* and *values*. It's the name lookup that you're thinking of and that can be done unqualified. But in the present situation there are no names.